# My Request by token query is returning null

Tags: reactjs, express, graphql, apollo-server

After the token has been stored in the Local Storage, I have a function where I can load the data of the currentStudent when the token is verified but the function is returning null.

this is my resolvers code

```
  getCurrentStudent: async (
      root,
      { studentId },
      { currentStudent, Student }
    ) => {
      if (!currentStudent) {
        return null;
      }
      const student = await Student.findOne({
        studentId: currentStudent.studentId
      });
      return student;
    }
```

and then i tried to make a context with the ApolloServer instance

```
const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  context: async ({ req }) => {
    const token = req.headers["authorization"];
    if (token !== null) {
      try {
        const currentStudent = await jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET);
        req.currentStudent = currentStudent;
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

this should verify my token and return the currentUser.

Comment: A 400 status means the query you sent to your server failed to pass validation. Check the complete error message you're getting from the server. If you can't figure out what's wrong based on the error you receive, update your question to include the full error message as well as the query you are sending.

Comment: Yes thank you, I have misplled something in my graphql query, now when im querying, it is giving me "nameofthequery": null

Answer (score 0):

The function you pass to context should return a context object, or a Promise that will resolve to one:

```
context: async ({ req }) => {
  const token = req.headers["authorization"];
  let currentStudent;
  if (token !== null) {
    try {
      const currentStudent = await jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET);
      currentStudent = currentStudent;
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
  return {
    currentStudent,
  };
}
```

You can then utilize that context inside any of your resolvers, for example:

```
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    currentStudent: (root, args, context) => {
      return context.currentStudent;
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Same results, The results are giving me the value of null.

Comment: Please update your question to include the relevant parts of your schema and your actual resolver code.